# Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having some trouble creating tables using Hibernate with the following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'
>
> Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table services (id varchar(255) not null auto_increment, adult_cost double precision not null, child_cost double precision not null, partner_id varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB]

My code for the ID column is as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

From what I understand, this exception normally occurs when you try to assign an auto_increment to a non-numeric but as you can see - I've defined id as an int.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've just tested one of my code by changing   Long id  into  int id, and it work very well so I think you have to check the type of id column in your DB it might be different from what you do expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`  instead of `GenerationType.AUTO`. Mysql doesn't use table to generate id values.

Comment: yes. Either use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

When you select primary key or any key select and give apply/go then check whether its auto incremented with not null specification then its defenitly works